# Pilot fails even though it finishes uploading the Build

Tags: xcode, travis-ci, fastlane

I am currently using pilot together with fastlane in travis-ci and everything works fine, my builds are being uploaded to TestFlight and published to the internal Testers as it should.

But the thing I don't understand is, fastlane finishs with exit code 1 and says "You must provide an answer for this question" without even asking something.

This is the weird output:

```
[12:29:40]: Successfully finished processing the build
[12:29:40]: You can now tweet: 
[12:29:40]: iTunes Connect #iosprocessingtime 15 minutes
[12:29:40]: Distributing new build to testers
[12:29:43]: Variable Dump:
[12:29:43]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios beta_ci", :SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE=>"app-store", :LATEST_TESTFLIGHT_BUILD_NUMBER=>3, :BUILD_NUMBER=>"4", :IPA_OUTPUT_PATH=>"/Users/travis/build/KWStudios/Walk-iOS/Pods.ipa", :DSYM_OUTPUT_PATH=>"/Users/travis/build/KWStudios/Walk-iOS/Pods.app.dSYM.zip", :XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE=>"/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-03-01/Pods 2016-03-01 12.06.19.xcarchive"}
[12:29:43]: You must provide an answer for this question.
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|                     fastlane summary                     |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                              | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying required fastlane version | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform                    | 0           |
| 3    | cocoapods                           | 110         |
| 4    | match                               | 27          |
| 5    | match                               | 4           |
| 6    | latest_testflight_build_number      | 8           |
| 7    | increment_build_number              | 2           |
| 8    | gym                                 | 413         |
| 9    | pilot                               | 995         |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
[12:29:43]: fastlane finished with errors
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  An error occured. Please enable crash reports using `fastlane enable_crash_reporting`.
  This makes resolving issues much easier and helps improve fastlane.
  The reports will be stored securely on getsentry.com.
  More information about privacy: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/1.33.3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/spaceship-0.21.1/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:219:in `handle_itc_response': [!] You must provide an answer for this question. (Spaceship::TunesClient::ITunesConnectError)
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/spaceship-0.21.1/lib/spaceship/tunes/tunes_client.rb:538:in `update_build_trains!'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/spaceship-0.21.1/lib/spaceship/tunes/build_train.rb:118:in `update_testing_status!'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/pilot-1.4.1/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:124:in `distribute_build'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/pilot-1.4.1/lib/pilot/build_manager.rb:26:in `upload'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/actions/pilot.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:35:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:129:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:128:in `chdir'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:128:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:68:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:36:in `call'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:36:in `call'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:52:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:46:in `chdir'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:46:in `execute'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:46:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:30:in `handle'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/bin/fastlane:38:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:428:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane_core-0.36.9/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:23:in `run!'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/commander-4.3.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/bin/fastlane:156:in `run'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/gems/fastlane-1.63.1/bin/fastlane:162:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
The command "fastlane beta_ci" exited with 1.
```

Is there anything I can do in order to prevent travis from exiting with 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple introduced new step in TestFlight release process that requires answer for availability of encryption in the product. To ensure that this question does not interrupt automatic release flow following line should be added into `Info.plist` in case if you do not use cryptography:

    `<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>`